# Java JFrame not receiving input

Tags: java, swing

I have a JFrame set up with a keyListener added onto it at runtime, but when the Frame loads, there is a brief moment in which input will be received and then it just stops receiving input all together, here is the `Keyboard.java` code:

```
package uk.connorwright.rain.input;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Keyboard implements KeyListener {

private boolean[] keys = new boolean[120];
public boolean up, down, left, right;

public void update() {
    up = keys[KeyEvent.VK_UP] || keys[KeyEvent.VK_W];
    down = keys[KeyEvent.VK_DOWN] || keys[KeyEvent.VK_S];
    left = keys[KeyEvent.VK_LEFT] || keys[KeyEvent.VK_A];
    right = keys[KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT] || keys[KeyEvent.VK_D];

}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

}
```

This is the code in `Game.java` which relates to the Keyboard input:

```
private Keyboard key;
```

**...**

```
key = new Keyboard();

    frame.addKeyListener(key);
```

**....**


        public void update() {

             key.update();

```
    if (key.up) {
        y--;
    }

    if (key.down) {
        y++;
    }

    if (key.left) {
        x--;
    }

    if (key.right) {
        x++;
    }
}
```

**...**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
         Game game = new Game();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KeyListener` is a poor choice, it's responsible for generating events for a component when it is focusable AND it has focus.

Instead, you should considering using the Key Bindings API, which provides you the means to decide at what focus level it should generate key events

See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details.

Comment: I'd prefer to get my code working and then make that transition, but at the moment when I start it up, it gets input until I click, then it stops receiving input

Comment: @BasicsCoding If you want to get your code working, then use a the Key Bindings API.  As I stated, the component will only raise key board events if the component that the listener is registered to is focusable AND has focus

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but I think it's probable that your KeyListener needs a component which has the keyboard focus, and a JFrame will never have that.  Only subcomponents of the frame will have the focus.

From the tutorial:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

> Specifically, key events are fired by the component with the keyboard
>   focus when the user presses or releases keyboard keys. For detailed
>   information about focus, see How to Use the Focus Subsystem.

So no key events if you don't have focus.

Comment: In my main method I have `game.frame.requestFocus();` just after making it visible, and then the next line of code after that is `game.start();`

Comment: And immediately after you call `requestFocus()` the system sends the focus to some other component which actually needs the focus.  "Request" means just that, it might not work.

Comment: I've added `frame.requestFocus()` to my `public void update()` method, and that has worked

Comment: Yeah, because stealing focus from what ever currently has focus isn't annoying to the user in any way

Comment: @MadProgrammer all it does is flash in the taskbar?

Comment: @BasicsCoding Not what I mean, some component has keyboard focus, which the user interacting with, now you've stolen focus away from the component to solve a problem which would better solved with by using the right API, this means that the user is now in a constant battle with your app, between what they want to do and what you want the app to be able to do.  In the end, it's a hack, which is just going to complicate what could other wise be easily solved

Comment: @BasicsCoding And calling `requestFocus` on window based component means that no other windows can have focus, so yeah, now tripling annoying :P